# How often is HDD data completely unrecoverable?

Tags: hard-drive, hardware-failure, hard-drive-recovery

My question is simple. Let's say I'm an average desktop PC or laptop user. My hard drive fails. I take it to an expert to recover lost data.

How often is the data recovering process absolutely and completely impossible ?

Anyone here have a lot of experience with this ? From your experience, what percentage of the time is data forever gone... no matter what you try ?

Thank you in advance for any answer.

Comment: *"My question is simple"* --  How often does it rain?

Comment: From my personal experience, the amount of data lost is lowest when the user has a good backup system.

Comment: This is an unanswerable question.  Its no different than saying, "I dont feel well. Will I get better?"  Without diagnosing the issue, there is no way to say.  You could just need sleep, have a cold, or have an incurable, terminal disease.  The same goes for your hard drive.

Comment: @sawdust -- My question is far from that general. I was merely curious about how often data (in it's entirety or parts of it) can be recovered from a failing hard drive disk. I read 9 times out of 10 at least part of the data can be recovered but that didn't seem to take into account the multiple ways to recover data. More than anything, I was simply looking for a professional opinion... someone who did a lot of work trying to recover data for clients and maybe they could have told me ''how often'' from their personal experience. But thanks for the snarky comment.

Comment: @Keltari -- I feel you did not understand my question. I was not talking about a specific case. I don't currently have a problem with a hard drive. I was simply looking for feedback from someone who has experience in this field. Because I'm curious about stats and enjoy learning.

Comment: @At0mic -- No kidding ? So if I have multiple backups and something fails, I can recover data ? That's a novel concept ! Thank you for your precious insight :)

Comment: @ChaosWalker I understood perfectly.  This is an unanswerable question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there are any such statistics.

A professional data recovery company could report on the statistics where data was non recoverable. But such companies see only a small percentage of drives that fail and I doubt those they do see are the typical case. And in many cases data could be recovered but the client is unwilling to pay the price

When a typical home user experiences a drive failure they either recover the data on their own or fail to do so. Either that or they take it to a shop that does the same. But when they fail it is typically because they either lack the knowledge or the motivation to proceed further. In many cases a professional could recover the data, but they never see the drive. Most home users know that professional data recovery is expensive and not worth the cost. There are no statistics for this.

Wise home and business users maintain backups of their data. When a drive failure is identified it is replaced and the data is recovered from the backups. There is no serious attempt at data recovery. How successful would recovery be if it were tried? Nobody knows.

Never rely on data recovery. It will fail you when you need it the most. Professional data recovery is expensive. Professional anything always is. Be a wise user and maintain backups of your data. That way a drive failure is only an inconvenience. You won't know or care if data recovery was possible or what it might have cost you.

Comment: Thank you so much for your thorough answer ! This is exactly the kind of insight I was looking for. You make very good points, such stats aren't available because of the multiple reasons you mentioned. And if stats are available, they are incomplete and inaccurate because of those same reasons. And I agree data backups are always the best bet :) Accepted answer.